# AZURE ML getting model weights

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I have deployed a regression model on azure ML , is it possible to get the model weights/coefficients of the model programatically from azure, rather than getting predicted value? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Currently we do not feature exporting weights from the models including with Azure Machine Learning.

If you have a method for extracting weights from Python models, you may be able to work this out using the execute Python Script module.

The primary purpose of Azure Machine Learning is to make deployable and scalable web services from the machine learning modules. Though the authoring experience for creating ML models is great, it is not intended to be a place to create and export models, but instead a place to create and operationalize your models.

*UPDATE* New features may make this answer outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the help :)

Comment: You can always add a "Writer" module connected to the "Evaluate Model", and write the model weights/coefficients to a blob storage or any other supported output, and access this output programatically

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do so, in your training experiment add an output to your evaluate model module then select deploy webservice right away without going through the predictive experiment option.

[image]

Once You publish and click the TEST button You should the values as below
[image]